# php download function gives me an empty file instead

Tags: php

Heres my code

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'];

if (file_exists("uploaded_files\\" .$file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile("uploaded_files\\" .$file);
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Download failed";
}
?>
```

I'm trying to allow user to download any file that they uploaded in my folder, called uploaded_files

Comment: is there any way to my download function work as intended?

Comment: What are the permissions on the 'uploaded files' directory?

Comment: all of them have read and write access

Comment: update your question pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your file location because `readfile()` needs the absolute path of the file

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file']
$file = "uploaded_files/".$file;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}else {
  echo "Download failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: readfile("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\FYPproject\\uploaded_files\\" .$file);

still doesnt work

Comment: THANKS! HOW STUPID OF ME.

Comment: @Calvin, we all are kind of a stupid here bro. :P Best of Luck